# Chi-square minimization error

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, fitting

I'm trying to fit some data into a model using the standard procedure of minimizing the chi-square function using this code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
a0 = 1;
b0 = 2;

sol[a_, b_] := 
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == -a*x[t] + Sin[t], y'[t] == a*x[t] - b*y[t]^2, 
    z'[t] == b*y[t] - Cos[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0}, {x, y,
     z}, {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

F[t_] := x[t] + y[t]^2 + z[t]^3;

wsol[a_, 
   b_] := (wsol[a, b] = 
    NDSolve[{w'[t] - w[t] - ((F[t] /. sol[a, b])[[1]]) == 0, 
      w[0] == 0}, w, {t, 0, 10}]);

model[t_, a_, b_] := (w[t] /. wsol[a, b])[[1]] // Chop;

SeedRandom[1264645]; 
rangoT = Range[0, 9, 0.5];
ndat = Length[rangoT];

DATA = Table[{t, 
    model[t, a0, b0] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .1]], 
    RandomReal[{.05, .1}]}, {t, rangoT}];

chi2[a_, b_] := 
 Sum[((DATA[[i, 2]] - model[DATA[[i, 1]], a, b])/DATA[[i, 3]])^2, {i, 
   1, ndat}]

FindMinimum[chi2[a, b], {w, 0.9}, {b, 1.1}]
```

But when I run it I get error messages from the FindMinimum command related to NDSolve and ReplaceAll. Everything runs just fine until using that command. I was wondering why's not working and what should be changed.

Comment: What error message do you get? Do you still get an answer?

Comment: The evaluation of `DATA` doesn't work. `NDSolve` throws copious errors at that point. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: @MarcoB that's my case... But everything appears when using the FindMinimum. Errors related to NDSolve and ReplaceAll... If you evaluate chi2 function, everything is ok

Comment: 1. So something is already wrong in the line `DATA=...`, please correct the description. 2. Use something rather than `t` in the `Table` will fix the issue. (Don't forget `t` is already used in those `NDSolve`s and you haven't localize them! ) 3. `{w, 0.9}` in last line is obviously wrong. 4. You need `_?NumericQ`, see this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/1871

Answer (score 2):

Three comments:

1. solve for all variables simultaneously instead of solving for $(x,y,z)$ first and $w$ second,
2. use `NonlinearModelFit` instead of writing your own least-squares solver, and
3. going all the way up to $t_{\text{max}}=10$ seems a bit much and the differential equation seems to diverge.

```
tmax = 6;
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
        x'[t] == -a*x[t] + Sin[t],
        y'[t] == a*x[t] - b*y[t]^2,
        z'[t] == b*y[t] - Cos[t],
        w'[t] - w[t] == x[t] + y[t]^2 + z[t]^3,
        x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, w[0] == 0},
        {x, y, z, w}, {t, 0, tmax}, {a, b}, 
        MaxSteps -> Infinity];
model[t_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := sol[a, b][[4]][t]

a0 = 1;
b0 = 2;
SeedRandom[1264645];
rangoT = Range[0, tmax, 0.5];
ndat = Length[rangoT];

DATA = Table[{t,
              model[t, a0, b0] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .1]],
              RandomReal[{.05, .1}]}, {t, rangoT}];

result = NonlinearModelFit[DATA[[All, 1 ;; 2]], model[t, a, b],
           {{a, a0}, {b, b0}}, t,
           VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &),
           Weights -> 1/DATA[[All, 3]]^2]

result["ParameterTable"]
```

$$
\begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 a & 1.0013 & 0.00103671 & 965.843 & \text{1.8409735010100922$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-28} \\
 b & 1.9994 & 0.000490316 & 4077.78 & \text{2.423162678987459$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-35} \\
\end{array}
$$

### update: analytic $x(t)$

Note that the differential equation for $x(t)$ can be solved analytically, which improves the stability and accuracy of the result:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == -a*x[t] + Sin[t], x[0] == 1}, x[t], t] // FullSimplify
(*    {{x[t] -> ((2 + a^2) E^(-a t) - Cos[t] + a Sin[t])/(1 + a^2)}}    *)
```

Therefore we can define the problem more accurately as

```
x[a_, t_] = ((2 + a^2) E^(-a t) - Cos[t] + a Sin[t])/(1 + a^2);
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
        y'[t] == a*x[a, t] - b*y[t]^2,
        z'[t] == b*y[t] - Cos[t],
        w'[t] - w[t] == x[a, t] + y[t]^2 + z[t]^3,
        y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, w[0] == 0},
        {y, z, w}, {t, 0, tmax}, {a, b}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
model[t_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := sol[a, b][[3]][t]
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks... The use of  `ParametricNDSolveValue` and `NonlinearModelFit` solved those issues. What I was wondering is that if could plot the contour plots for sigma amplitudes using the results of `NonlinearModelFit` and the definition of chi-square function used above.

Comment: @Syn1110 `Graphics[result["ParameterConfidenceRegion"], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {a, b}]` shows the confidence ellipse of the parameters. Please have a look at `result["Properties"]` to see all the goodies you can get out of the fit result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That only shows confidence region at 1sigma amplitude right? Is there a way to obtain 2sigma and 3sigma?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by "NDSolve". It should localize the dummy variable "t", but fails to do so. Consider:

```
t = 0; 
NDSolve[{f'[t] == f[t], f[0] == 1}, f, {t, 0, 10}]
```

This gives the error message:

[image]

I think this is a bug.

Comment: No, it's not. `NDSolve` simply doesn't have attribute like `HoldAll` that adjusts the evaluation order, this is by design.

Comment: @xzczd Do you see any reason why this should be by design?

Comment: Otherwise things like this will happen on `Solve`/`DSolve`/`NDSolve`: `opt=PlotStyle->Red; Plot[x,{x,0,1},opt]`

Comment: Actually in early versions, even `domain = {x, 0, 1}; Plot[x, domain]` is enough to cause trouble:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpOl8.png This is all because of the `HoldAll`. If `Solve`, etc. behaves similarly, it'll be rather inconvenient. (Just imagine the world that code like `eq = {a + b == 0, a - 2 b == 3}; vars = {a, b}; Solve[eq, vars]` results in failure! )